# for-loop controlling the number of times the Dice are rolled. (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop

I am making a Java program to allow the user to input the number of times the dice are to be rolled. I am using a for loop with a timesRolled variable to control how many times to loop through the program. I want to add all of the random dice values to get the sum.

```
int timesRolled = 4;
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < timesRolled; i++) {
    int rand1 = getRandom(1,6); // getrandom is a function withing the template.
    result = rand1 ;
    outputln(result);
}
```

Comment: Change it to `result += rand1;` and move `outputln()` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add the current value of result to the newly determined dice value in every iteration, and assign that to the result so: `result = result + rand1` or `result += rand1` for short. Also calling the `outputln(result);` inside the for loop, will output the cumulative sum every iteration, so you might want to move it out the to output only once in the end.

```
int timesRolled = 4;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < timesRolled; i++) {
        int rand1 = getRandom(1,6); // getrandom is a function withing the template.
        result += rand1 ;
    }
outputln(result);
```